# C Threaded Sockets - tcp with TLS, Can't get ip/ether packet headers

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, openssl

thanks for reading this question. Have been working for a while on C sockets - specifically c threaded tcp sockets with tls. Using the Openssl API.

I have been facing an issue for some time now where I can get the source IP and Port - e.g `printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(d->addr.sin_addr), ntohs(d->addr.sin_port));`.

The problem is that I need all the data - Ethernet and IP where I can look at source and destination IP's, MAC addresses, Protocol, TTL and the list goes on.

Tried multiple examples from the web like this from Binary tides

```
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
unsigned short iphdrlen;

struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)Buffer;
iphdrlen =iph->ihl*4;

memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;
fprintf(logfile,"   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(iph->check));
fprintf(logfile,"   |-Source IP        : %s\n",inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
fprintf(logfile,"   |-Destination IP   : %s\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
```

But I keep on getting "Junk Data". Basically the IP's and other fields are strange and random like.

SSL_read() puts the data into a buffer (the https request basically) so at that point I'm already too late?
I tried reading the socket before attempting SSL_Accept(), so reading from an unencrypted socket, I still get the junk data.

Basically any help with:

1) c examples

2) do I need to use BIO?

3) what process do I follow to capture that data

in my main I just loop e.g

```
for (; ;) {
    memset(&d->addr, 0, sizeof(d->addr));
    d->len = sizeof(d->addr);
    if ( (d->client = accept(d->server, (struct sockaddr*)&d->addr, &d->len)) > 0 ) {
        pthread_create(&connection_thread, NULL, handleGuestConnection, (void *) d);
```

here is a snippet of the threaded function:

```
data *d = socketData;

SSL *ssl;
ssl = SSL_new(d->ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, d->client);

int returnStatus = handleGuestSSLAccept(ssl);

switch (returnStatus) {
    case 1: {
        break;
        //Bad Socket
    }
    case 2: {
        char *reply = HTTPHeaderResponse(2);
        write(d->client, reply, strlen(reply));
        break;
        //Redirect
    }
    case 3: {
        char buf[1024] = {0};
        int bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if ( bytes > 0 ) {
            buf[bytes] = '\0';
            char *reply = HTTPHeaderResponse(3);
            SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply));
        }
        break;
        //Good
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to understand that the correspondence between SSL data and TCP packets is not going to be 1-to-1. It can be pretty much anything to anything. Your best bet is to capture the low-level data completely separately, such as with a thread that uses libpcap or the like.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to see the low-level details of the protocol?  Is this just a learning exercise?  If so, then I recommend `wireshark`.  For TLS, the command-line `openssl s_client` and `s_server` tools have a nice debug option for the TLS messaging.  If you're trying to validate clients by inspecting the protocol details, maybe there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I've been looking into that, do you know of any examples ? I haven't been able to successfully implement a working version

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - thanks, those are good products, but I'm more interested in creating something in C/C++/Go that can do what Wireshark and Openssl do - for improving my programming and understanding the low level sockets

Comment: Then you should look at the code of wireshark and/or tcpdump to see how they do it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have been trying the same thing. I like little clarification. Please confirm that that u are saying maintain a tcp socket in one thread and read the low level protocol headers using raw socket in separate thread.  TCP socket will simply maintain tcp connection while raw socket gives ip header. Is that what u mean? For that I am thinking to share data and headers between two threads I can use shared linkedlist of data buffers and header buffers. And use mutex to synchronize buffers. Does this make sense?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone looking to achieve a Proxy with a built in firewall - it is not a step 1-10 programming task. You can build a proxy with C/C++ or use Golang like I did - happy to share if you need. In terms of filtering packets I accomplished this by inserting a module written in C into kernel space using insmod. The reason you cannot do this from your application is this - Once a packet passes from Kernel space to UserSpace, Headers are all stripped off. So the only way to capture headers is to insert a module into the kernel space that is triggered every time a packet arrives. tcpdump.org has a few good articles but that would be using their methods, I decided to use my own and went with a kernel module

Answer (score 0):

In this code here:

```
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
```

the `sock_raw` is a hint. You need something called a "raw socket", which gives you access to the underlying packets at some level (depending on your platform, that might include the ethernet packet level, or just IP).

References: [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html), [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548.aspx).

Comment: Yes but is it possible to implement openssl onto of a raw socket? When I've tried changing my socket `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);` to `socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);` I get a number of errors about the type of socket

Comment: I've tried it again - You can't set it to listen on a specified port (or at least I can't see how), so that would defeat the purpose. Any other idea ?

Comment: @allThingsLinux You are trying to combine two completely different things. One is the TCP level use of the connection. The other is getting the raw data that you want. You are trying to turn the code that does the first thing into the code that does the second thing, but the second thing requires completely different code. Get the first thing right, get SSL working. Then write separate code to gather the raw data you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - SSL is working fine up to 10 000 threaded connections. As mentioned, any ideas on capturing raw data of tcp/ethernet headers.
Hence I asked for three things - any code examples, any info on the process flow of tls data into raw data  and lastly would I need to use BIO.

Comment: @allThingsLinux Take a look at wireshark, libpcap, tcpdump, or any other program that does exactly this. Your SSL code is fine. Don't mess with it. Now build the other thing you need.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks you were right to look at how tcpdump does it and it is two very different parts to this one idea I had